# Android Alarm Manager Not working when app is Killed

Tags: android

I want to schedule an alarm that fire's every 1 min and wake up my app. It is working on Emulator, but not working on customised OS phones like VIVO, OPPO, MIUI etc. I have written a Sticky service & a broadcast Receiver. When service will be destroyed or TaskRemoved, i called method named sendBroadcast() that will trigger my Broadcast Receiver and My Brodcast Receiver will start the service again by calling startservice(intent) method. But this is Not working when app is killed. When app is in Foreground it working fine. I want Alarm Manger will work when an app is Killed.

This is my code below--

My MainActivity.java file to start the service--

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmService.class);
    startService(alarmIntent);


}   }
```

My Sticky Service code is --

```
public class AlarmService extends Service
{

private String TAG ="AlarmService";
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    sendBroadcast();
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    sendBroadcast();
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}


@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    sendBroadcast();
    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}

private void sendBroadcast()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AlarmReceiver.class);
    //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_INCLUDE_STOPPED_PACKAGES);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 5);
    if (alarmManager != null)
    {
        //System.currentTimeMillis() + (i * 100),
        alarmManager.setRepeating(
                AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                System.currentTimeMillis(),
                60000,
                pendingIntent);
    }
}}
```

My BroadcastReceiver is as follows --

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    // For our recurring task, we'll just display a message
    Toast.makeText(context, "I'm running", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    generateNotification(context);

    //restartJobScheduler(context);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O) restartJobScheduler(context);
    else restartService(context);

}

private void restartJobScheduler(Context context)
{
    Log.i("MyBroadCastReceiver", "onReceive");
    //context.startForegroundService(service);
    FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
            .setService(MyJobService.class)
            .setTag("myFCMJob")
            .build();
    dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
}

private void restartService(Context context)
{
    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
    context.startService(restartServiceIntent);

}}
```

My Android.Manifest file is as below---

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".MyJobService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <service android:name=".AlarmService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:label="Alarm Service"
        android:stopWithTask="false">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.tas9.alarmmanager.AlarmService" />
        </intent-filter>

    </service>
```

Comment: had you got any solution for this?

Comment: @pihu, No! not get any strong solution on it. But reached to the root cuase of problem, the problem is from the manufacturer's side, to improve battery performance, manufacturers are doing this, once you killed any app the services and broadcasts you wrote for it were also being killed/stopped. Though in case of whatsapp its all being just a myth, because all manufacturer's are allowing whatsapp as an whitelisted app.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On some devices you will need to manually add your app to the list of apps allowed to run in the background. Otherwise, even with a "sticky" `Service`, Android will not restart the `Service` once the process has been killed. Manufacturers do this to save battery life.

In the settings, there should be a way to add your app to the list of "protected apps" or "apps allowed to run in the background". Look in the power management settings or the Apps settings.

Comment: Yes, It is only had a problem on customised OS phones such as Redmi, MIUI, OPPO, VIVO etc. But the whatsapp have achieved this solution. Whatsapp giving me push notification even when app is killed. How is this working any Idea?

Comment: Popular applications like Whatsapp Facebook Gmail are pre-installed and preapproved by the manufacturer so they are already added to tge list of apps allowed to run in the background. You would have to contact the manufacturer and make a deal directly with them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. What is the process for this, have you ever gone through this way? And is there any way to programatically pre-approved the app or whitelist the app by programatically?  Please Let me know. Thanks again!

Comment: I had the same issue on One Plus 7T. I had updated phone App setting under Battery Optimization to "Don't Optimize". It worked for me.

Comment: @RohanShinde no, sorry. There is no way to programmatically do this. You need to have an agreement with the manufacturer to have your app pre-approved for this list.

Comment: "Don't Optimize" solution worked for me too on OPPO but nothing is working on Vivo, any other way to make it work.

Answer (score 26):

Ok, so i personally wasted 6 hours today, doing everything which is described in the official doc - https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html. I also tried different setups like - ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, RTC_WAKEUP etc. Nothing really helped me, my alarms would only work when the app was opened, and as soon as i would close the app(removed it from the task bar) no alarms would fire. I've found the solution here by accident - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/150080941#comment5 - we are only seeing this when the app is launched via the green play button from studio, and not in an indepdent session such as when sideloading the apk or when clicking on the app icon from the device.

TL;DR - Try to test you alarm manager functionality by sideloading the apk, and not by launching it via green play button in Android Studio.

Comment: I had to unplug device from cable and I've launched it and closed 3 times ;)

Comment: Saved the day Man!!

Comment: Thank you very much, i wasted 8 hours, and tried whole world's library to fix alarm manager not working in react native, this answer saved time.

Answer (score 17):

The problem is the way, you are trying to install the app.

**App is in Foreground or background state:**
In such case installing the app via the Android Studio's Run (play) button will work fine

**App is being killed:**
Build the APK, download & install in your phone, it will work fine. Installing the app via Android Studio will not work.

To sum up, simply build the APK (Build --> Build APK), it will work in every scenario.

This is just a clarification of the above answer by @nvr

Comment: This was the solution for me after successfully destroying 3 hours

Comment: Thanks for this. Someone created an issue on my Project on this and I think this might just be the issue.